# I see a response message "Your message was sent successfully" in contact form 7 plugin, but did not received any mail

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created one form using contact form7 plugin in wordpress. let example, If ABC fill the form, I will get mail from ABC and then ABC will get thank you message from our domain. but the problem is that I am not getting any mail from that person. I have used email id of my domain in From section. like sujata

when anyone submit form he can see thank you message in green box on site and also recive thank you mail.

I have used mail(2) option to send thank you mail.

please help me to solve my problem.

Comment: First, have you checked your spam folder? Second, you could use [MailCatcher](https://mailcatcher.me/) to debug your problem. Make it listen to the SMTP port your app is using (25 by default) and do a form submit. If you don't receive any mail in MailCatcher, it means your server configuration is not properly setup. If you need help, let me know.

Comment: Check if you server actually supports sending emails or not. You can use this plugin for checking: [https://wordpress.org/plugins/check-email/](https://wordpress.org/plugins/check-email/)

Comment: @MdKowsarHossain I tried check-email plugin and I received test mail from my server. but if try to send mail through contact form I didn't get it. I got only thank you mail.